# Join Modelo con sentencia

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy utilizando kanboard con un plugin llamado MetaMagik para poder añadir mas campos a las tareas de los proyectos.
A la hora de exportar a csv quiero añadir un campo que me calcule el tiempo que lleva abierto la tarea.

He probado diferentes maneras pero no consigo que funcione.

```
protected function getTasks($project_id, $from, $to)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($from)) {
            $from = $this->dateParser->removeTimeFromTimestamp($this->dateParser->getTimestamp($from));
        }

        if (!is_numeric($to)) {
            $to = $this->dateParser->removeTimeFromTimestamp(strtotime('+1 day', $this->dateParser->getTimestamp($to)));
        }

        return $this->db->table(TaskModel::TABLE)

            ->columns(

                TaskModel::TABLE . '.id',
                SwimlaneModel::TABLE . '.name AS swimlane_name',
                CategoryModel::TABLE . '.name AS category_name',
               
                '(SELECT DISTINCT '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.value FROM '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE.' WHERE '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.task_id='.TaskModel::TABLE .'.id and '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.name="Type" ) AS prueba',
                '(SELECT DISTINCT '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.value FROM '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE.' WHERE '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.task_id='.TaskModel::TABLE .'.id and '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.name="Identifyer" ) AS prueba2',
                '(SELECT DISTINCT '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.value FROM '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE.' WHERE '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.task_id='.TaskModel::TABLE .'.id and '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.name="Area" ) AS prueba3',
                '(SELECT DISTINCT '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.value FROM '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE.' WHERE '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.task_id='.TaskModel::TABLE .'.id and '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.name="Reference" ) AS prueba13',
                '(SELECT DISTINCT '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.value FROM '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE.' WHERE '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.task_id='.TaskModel::TABLE .'.id and '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.name="Score_Before" ) AS prueba4',

                ColumnModel::TABLE . '.title AS estado',
                'uc.name AS creator_name',
                UserModel::TABLE . '.name AS assignee_name',
                TaskModel::TABLE . '.date_creation',
                TaskModel::TABLE . '.title',
                TaskModel::TABLE . '.description',
                '(SELECT DISTINCT '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.value FROM '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE.' WHERE '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.task_id='.TaskModel::TABLE .'.id and '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.name="Root_Cause" ) AS causa',

//--------------------------------PRUEBAS-------------------------------------------

                '(SELECT CASE WHEN (max(CASE WHEN '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.name = "Closed_Date" then '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.value END)) = "" THEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME('.TaskModel::TABLE .'.date_creation, "%Y-%m-%d"))
                ELSE DATEDIFF(max(CASE WHEN '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.name = "Closed_Date" then '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.value END),  FROM_UNIXTIME('.TaskModel::TABLE .'.date_creation, "%Y-%m-%d"))
                END AS OPEN_DAYS)',


                // '(SELECT CASE WHEN (max(CASE WHEN '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.name = "Closed_Date" THEN '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE. '.value END)) = ""
                // THEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME('.TaskModel::TABLE . '.date_creation, "%Y-%m-%d"))
                // ELSE DATEDIFF(max(CASE WHEN '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE . '.name = "Closed_Date" THEN '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE . '.value END),  FROM_UNIXTIME('.TaskModel::TABLE . '.date_creation, "%Y-%m-%d"))
                // END AS OPEN_DAYS FROM '.TaskModel::TABLE . ' left join '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE .' on '.TaskModel::TABLE . '.id = '.MetadataExtendModel::TABLE .'.task_id 
                // group by '.TaskModel::TABLE . '.id)',

            )
            ->join(UserModel::TABLE, 'id', 'owner_id', TaskModel::TABLE)
            ->left(UserModel::TABLE, 'uc', 'id', TaskModel::TABLE, 'creator_id')
            //>join(TaskModel::TABLE, 'id', 'task_id', MetadataExtendModel::TABLE)
            //->left(MetadataExtendModel::TABLE, 'tk', 'task_id', TaskModel::TABLE, 'id')
            ->join(CategoryModel::TABLE, 'id', 'category_id', TaskModel::TABLE)
            ->join(ColumnModel::TABLE, 'id', 'column_id', TaskModel::TABLE)
            ->join(SwimlaneModel::TABLE, 'id', 'swimlane_id', TaskModel::TABLE)
            ->join(ProjectModel::TABLE, 'id', 'project_id', TaskModel::TABLE)
            ->gte(TaskModel::TABLE . '.date_creation', $from)
            ->lte(TaskModel::TABLE . '.date_creation', $to)
            ->eq(TaskModel::TABLE . '.project_id', $project_id)
            ->asc(TaskModel::TABLE.'.id')
            ->findAll();
    }
```

En el código he separado con guiones para que se vea las pruebas que he hecho, pero ninguna me funciona de la manera que quiero. Deberían aparecerme todas las tareas entre un rango de fecha pero solo me aparece una.
También he comentado los join que he probado. La sentencia mas larga en base de datos me funciona perfectamente.

Gracias.